# How to make a UIScrollView scroll up effect as UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to make my scroll view scroll up and down like a UITableView does even if content size fits the device screen size. But after scroll up, the final content size must be the same as the start content size which is zero. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: table view is built on scroll view, and scroll view cannot scroll if content size is small or fits the screen. do you mean resizing the content based on your scroll/swipe gesture?

Comment: Yes, I want to make the user can scroll the scroll view up, but when she/he finishes the scroll event, the scroll view again automatically sets it content size to the start value (zero) with smooth animation as table view does

Comment: Are you want the bouncing effect?

Comment: Yes bouncing effect for both top and down

Answer (score 0):

Here a code snap it of bouncing effect when user scroll down like UITableView stretching effect

```
    class ScrollViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

         private var topViewHeightConstraintConstant: CGFloat = 259
            @IBOutlet weak var TopViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


                func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
                    if scrollView === self.scrollView {
                        if scrollView.isBouncingBottom || scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height {
                            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height), animated: false)
                        }
                        else if  scrollView.isBouncingTop && self.TopViewHeightConstraint.constant ==  topViewHeightConstraintConstant {
                            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 0), animated: false)
                        }
                        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
                            if self.TopViewHeightConstraint.constant + abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y) <= topViewHeightConstraintConstant {
                                self.TopViewHeightConstraint.constant += abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
                            }
                        } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 &&  self.TopViewHeightConstraint.constant >=
                            (self.view.frame.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.top - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom - self.contentViewHeight.constant) {
                            self.TopViewHeightConstraint.constant -= scrollView.contentOffset.y
                            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 0), animated: false)
                        }
                        view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }
                }
            }

            func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
             if scrollView !== self.scrollView {
                  TopViewHeightConstraint.constant = topViewHeightConstraintConstant
                 }
             }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try. Is there any easy way in the storyboard interface builder?

Comment: you can make an IBOutlet for the TopViewHeightConstraint from the storyboard